# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I keep getting this error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 8
    def salary_emp(self):

    ^
```

How can it match if I just defining function? Thanks in advance.

```
import math

class employee: 
    def __init__(self, name, lname, age):
        self.name = name
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age
    def salary_emp(self):
        print("{}".format((self.age - 25)*1000 + 50000))

empl1 = employee("Will", "Brown", 40)
salary_emp(empl1)

print(empl1)
print(empl1.name)
print(empl1.lname)
```

Comment: This code does not have the error you describe.  Edit your question to adjust the formatting so it is the same as your real code.

Comment: The only error I can spot is that you are calling `salary_emp` incorrectly. Instead, you should run that function as `empl_1.salary_emp()`

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces. Stop mixing tabs and spaces, and the problem will go away.

Comment: @user2357112 If that were the case, wouldn't the error be `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`?

Comment: try to run  `sed -i l your.py` to see if there is something wrong.

Comment: @JohnGordon: You'd think so, but no. Take a look in the edit view.

Comment: @user2357112 Right you are :-)

Comment: Like with many other such duplicates, the problem becomes readily apparent if we [check the raw source of OP's original attempt at the post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19979614-1b06-4ba8-92cd-492b854aa50a/view-source). The editor and/or Markdown processor here convert tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

One Question: What editor are you using?

Anyways, what usually happens is **either you are using a combination of spaces and tabs or while trasferring/pasting code from one file/editor to another**, the code tends to misplace itself. And this would cause sequential errors of the same type.

What usually works for me is:

> Whichever line is throwing the exception, go to its beginning and
>   backspace it till it comes in the same line as the previous line of
>   code. Now hit enter/return.

Or, **Replace all spaces by tabs**. Usually a good practice.

The exception throwing line should automatically go to its correct indented place.

Answer (score 0):

As @user2357112 pointed out, you're mixing tabs and spaces in the function definitions.

The lines for `__init__()` have leading tabs followed by spaces, but the lines for `salary_emp()` have only spaces.

Don't do this.  Use all tabs or all spaces.